# How to find the polyline between two points of a contour using OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, polygon, shapely

For my Python project with OpenCV.

How can I find the polygon drawn in red knowing the coordinates of points A, B, C and having the information on the image such as width and height?

[image]

At this moment I found only A and C as intersection points:

```py
line_end_1 = None
line_end_2 = None

print(f"list of segment (A-B , B-C): {line_list}")
print(f"Point B: {center_start}")
for line in line_list:
    
    contours = [[(0,0),(image_w,0)],[(image_w,0),(image_w, image_h)],[(image_w, image_h),(0,image_h)],[(0, image_h),(0,0)]]
    for contour in contours:
        line_end = find_intersection(line, contour)
        
        if line_end_1 is None and line_end is not None:
            line_end_1 = line_end
            print(f"Point A: {line_end_1}")
        elif line_end_2 is None and line_end is not None:
            line_end_2 = line_end
            print(f"Point C: {line_end_2}")`
```

With this result (example):

```
list of segment (A-B , B-C): [[(150, 275), (869, 625)], [(150, 275), (620, -372)]]
Point B: (150, 275)
Point A: (571, 480)
Point C: (349, 0)
```

Comment: For the top polygon, add the top-left and top-right corners of the image to A-B-C. I assume you know the dimensions of your image. Likewise for the bottom polygon, add the bottom-left corner to A-B-C. Perhaps I do not understand the issue. If so, then please clarify.  You can also threshold on red, then get the contours. The reduce the number of vertices.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Of course in a static way what you say would be sufficient

But everything must happen dynamically
That is, I have information on the position of the points but these can change during the execution of the program, so for example I have no information on which side was intercepted and how many lines I have to draw for my polygon (4 in the example below or 5 in the 'example above)

Comment: Follow the image boundary closest to and from A to C in the direction not including B.